# A generalized ellipse

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology, harmonic-analysis, plane-geometry

We know that an ellipse is the locus of all point $z$ in the plane with $$|z-a|+|z-b|=\lambda$$

where $a,b$ are two given points in the plane and $\lambda$ is  a  constant.

Now we consider the following generalization:

For three given points $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ define $$A_{\lambda}=\{z\in \mathbb{R}^{2} \;\text{with}\;\; |z-a|+|z-b|+|z-c|=\lambda\}$$

> How is the geometric description of $A_{\lambda}$? Is it a closed curve, at least when $\lambda$ is very large?

More generally, assume that $G$ is  a compact topological group with Haar measure $\mu$. Assume that $G$ is topologically embedded in the plane. Define:

$$A_{\lambda}=\{z\in \mathbb{R}^{2} \;\text{with}\;\; \int_{G}  |z-g|d\mu=\lambda\}$$

> Is the topology of $A_{\lambda}$ independent of choosing sufficiently large $\lambda$?

Comment: You might look at the $n$-ellipse, e.g., images at [this MSE posting](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/124371/237).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke  Thank you very much for the link.

Comment: Interesting historical footnote: James Clerk Maxwell, [*On the description of oval curves, and those having a plurality of foci; with remarks by Professor Forbes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QNosAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA89), **Proceedings of the Royal Society of Edinburgh** 2 #28 (1845-466), 89-91. Forbes actually read the paper before the Royal Society of Edinburgh (on 6 April 1846) because Maxwell was not allowed due to his age. Maxwell was only 14 years old at the time.

Comment: As explained in the paper cited in [said MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/124371/237), all $n$-ellipses are boundaries of compact and convex sets (though their algebraic closures aren't necessarily). The argument carries over to the case where you have any compactly supported finite measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^n$ and want to keep $f_\mu(z)=\int_{\mathbb R^n}|z-x|\,d\mu(x)$ constant. Simply regard $f_\mu$ along a straight line as a superposition of convex functions. Being the boundary of a compact convex set, the topology is clear (except for one degenerate case for each $\mu$ ...).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro  thank you very much for your very interesting historical remark.

Comment: @SebastianGoette  Of course your very interesting comment can be counted as an independent answer, thanks a lot for that.